# VBA to copy offset of cell referenced formulas

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I want to copy a range of cells that each have a formula which references another cell and paste those formulas into into another range using self defined relative references instead of the automatic excel ones.

For example, in this sheet I want to:

- manually select H4:H7 (the Jan formulas)
- run the macro
- manually move to the right two columns to cell J4 and use standard excel paste (ctrl_v) to output my desired output in formulas (the Feb formulas) in J4:J7.

here is the current sheet: 
[image: Regular view]

and here is the view of the sheet with ctrl~ to see the formulas:
[image: Formula view]

The formula view shows the required output in the J column with the Feb formulas. 
Since the Feb formulas are always referencing cells that are just one column over from the original Jan referenced cells, if the Feb column in formulas was one column over from Jan (ie if Feb were in column I) all I would need to do is copy the formulas from column H and paste them into column I. However here, since the structure of the sheet requires the formulas to be pasted into column J I need a macro that will copy the cells to the right of all the cells in column H that are referenced to the Jan values and do a simple paste into column J that will output my desired results.

this is the code that I am trying now and it only copies the formulas themselves but not the one cell offset.

```
Public Sub copy()


Dim source As Range
Dim target As Range

Set source = Range("H4:H7")
Set target = Range("J4:J7")

For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count
 target.Cells(i, 1).Formula = source.Cells(i, 1).Formula
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use the same formula that references the Values in row 3 to return the correct value based on the text?

Comment: For Example H4 could be `=INDEX($B$4:$D$4,,MATCH(H$3,$B$3:$D$3,0))` Then when you copy paste it the `H$3` will change to `J$3` and it will return the value from C4.

Comment: Copy your formulas from "H4:H7" to "H14:H17". MOVE them to "I14:I17", copy them to "J14:J17" and copy them to "J4:J7"!

Comment: @ScottCraner - i dont want to use index or match formulas for this. i need a macro that does this. The reason is that this example above is a simplified version of my final requirement which cant be linked to the top of the output. I need a macro that just copies the formula next to the referenced formula

Comment: @simple-solution this is exactly the manual workaround that I am using already but I posted this to see if someone can help me write the VBA that will do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a code for me site.  If you have code that is not working please [edit] your post and show what you have to this point.  Then explain where the error is.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried this but it just takes the formulas themselves and copies them. It doesnt take the formulas + one offset.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks please see OP for code that I am using

Comment: (Please don't post code in the comments. As you can see, it's hard to read. Please update your OP and format the code with the code tags, `{}`. Thank you!)